# What is the meaning of "a story of coy ill"?

Tags: meaning

I don't understand what "coy ill" means in this sentence : "a story of coy ill will that fooled no one" (about Kevin Spacey).

Thanks for your help,

Comment: It's "coy" "ill will", if that helps. Not "coy ill" "will".

Comment: Ill will expressed coyly.

Comment: An apostrophe might be of help here: "a story of coy ill-will that fooled no one". It could be loosely paraphrased to "a story of a distasteful animosity that fooled no one".

Comment: @MichaelD You mean a hyphen?

Comment: @Michael D Or a hyphen?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty and OldBrixtonian, yes my bad. A hyphen.

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid I'm still not sure to understand. Here's the entire phrase : "I wrote for Esquire, I did an elaborate rhetorical dance around the sexuality of Kevin Spacey, a story of coy ill-will that fooled no one". In this sentence, does coy mean falsely shy ?